# Page displays everything that is in the database

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.1

The PageSize field indicates that information should be displayed on one page, about eight objects, but the page displays everything that is in the database.

```
        private readonly IObjectRepository _objectRepository;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment;
        public int PageSize = 8;

        public HomeController(IObjectRepository objectRepository, IWebHostEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
        {
            _objectRepository = objectRepository;
            this.hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
        }

        public ViewResult Index(int objectPage)
        {
            var model = _objectRepository.GetAllObjects();
            model.OrderBy(o => o.Id)
                 .Skip((objectPage - 1) * PageSize)
                 .Take(PageSize);
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) "Does not work" is not a technical description of a problem.

Comment: Sry, my bad. Corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Skip](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.skip?view=netcore-2.2) and [Take](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take?view=netcore-2.2) return a new IEnumerable as a result, instead of modifying the existing one in place. So, you should replace this line:

```
model.OrderBy(o => o.Id)
             .Skip((objectPage - 1) * PageSize)
             .Take(PageSize);
```

with:

```
model=model.OrderBy(o => o.Id)
             .Skip((objectPage - 1) * PageSize)
             .Take(PageSize);
```

This way, you assign the new query value to the baseQuery and then when you enumerate it, it will return the expected entities.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I found another solution with Methanit, thanks him a lot.

1 - Changed my PageViewModel

```
public class PageViewModel
    {
        public int PageNumber { get; set; }
        public int TotalPages { get; set; }


    public PageViewModel(int count, int pageNumber, int pageSize)
    {
        PageNumber = pageNumber;
        TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(count / (double)pageSize);
    }

    public bool HasPreviousPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageNumber > 1);
        }
    }

    public bool HasNextPage
    {
        get
        {
            return (PageNumber < TotalPages);
        }
    }
}
```

2 - Changed method Index in Controller:

```
public IActionResult Index(int page = 1)
        {
            int pageSize = 6;
            var model = _objectRepository.GetAllObjects();
            var count = model.Count();
            var items = model.Skip((page - 1) * pageSize).Take(pageSize).ToList();
            PageViewModel pageViewModel = new PageViewModel(count, page, pageSize);
            IndexViewModel viewModel = new IndexViewModel
            {
                PageViewModel = pageViewModel,
                Objects = items
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

3 - The application is working correctly.
Thanks all a lot!